# Unity - Recover lost scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, backup

I had been working on a scene for hours when mysteriously my computer completely crashes and needs to restart I remember having saved several times when working so I wasn't scared. As I thought I had lost only maybe just 1-5min of work, I re-open Unity and to my surprise, my scene seemed to have reverted to one of my first saves, and because I had re-opened the scene, the `Temp/_BackupScenes` folder was erased...
So I was wondering, is there any way to recover Unity Scenes that does not imply the `_BackupScenes` folder? I don't think there is, but just to be sure because I very much remember saving the scene before it crashes...

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityCollaborateRollback.html
And: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBDflmDFAxI

These should give you all the info you need. I highly advise you to back up an export on a USB drive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is not what I am looking for because it includes the Backup files of Unity erased when I restarted unity. As there weren't many comments or/and answers I will suppose it isn't possible and will just re-do everything. Thank you

Comment: Becuase you're the only one who bothered to answer, I have put your answer as correct. You're welcome...

Comment: Okey dokey. Good luck in your project!